# Broken mysqld package preventing any other installation in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, linux-kernel, package-managers, dpkg

I am having this issue for quite a long period of time, it started when I wanted to change password for mysql which I forgot. I have followed a lot of documents to purge mysql from my system completely so that I can have a new password for a freshly installed mysql. But every time I install it I face the same problem and it asks me the same old password.

Currently I have purged mysql from my system but even though whenever I try to install anything, let's say openssh, I get the below logs after downloading the package.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
.    
.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 9069
Job for mysql.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: timeout) since Sat 2021-07-03 00:35:37 IST; 5ms ago
    Process: 9257 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 9278 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 9278 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Status: "Server shutdown complete"
      Error: 2 (No such file or directory)

Jul 03 00:35:37 gp-HP-Pavilion-Notebook systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Jul 03 00:35:37 gp-HP-Pavilion-Notebook systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jul 03 00:35:37 gp-HP-Pavilion-Notebook systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jul 03 00:35:41 gp-HP-Pavilion-Notebook systemd[1]: mysql.service: Got notification message from PID 10009, but reception only permitted for main PID 10007
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Is there any way to prevent this from happening every time when I install anything ?
It would be great if anyone could help in resolving this issue, because it is also blocking the proper installation of various other package.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. You might find you get better answers on [ubuntu.se] or [linux.se]

Answer (score 0):

The log says: *See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.*

`systemctl status mysql.service` will show the status of the mysql.service.

`systemctl stop mysql.service` will stop the mysql.service.

`systemctl start mysql.service` will start the mysql.service.

`systemctl enable mysql.service` will start the mysql.service at boot.

`systemctl disable mysql.service` will stop the starting of the mysql.service at boot.  (I think you need this one)

more info: `man systemctl`, and `systemctl --help`

Comment: I tried disabling it using ```systemctl disable mysql.service``` and then tried installing the package but still it gave me the same response.

Comment: Please add info about the log that you got when doing an uninstall of mysql-server. There should be info in there why it failed to uninstall. After the uninstall, reboot, and see if the proble in you question is solved.    More info on unistalling MySQL is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/172514/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql

Comment: Can you explain me @Luuk why it always comes up in every installation ?

Comment: Because it is somewhere in the configuration of systemd, see output of `systemctl list-unit-files | grep mysql`